# MongoDB thinks it's not on XFS despite being on one

Tags: mongodb

From what I can understand/read it should suffice to have the filesystem as XFS and the dbpath set to a folder on that disk. What else do I need to do to fix this? I moved the whole db folder from the initialized ext4 folder it was mounted on in the template. Is there a lock file I need to clear or something so that it re-checks the filesystem rather than thinking it's the old ext4 ?

**Log**

```
Server has startup warnings:
2019-08-28T08:34:56.863+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2019-08-28T08:34:56.863+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-08-28T08:34:56.863+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
```

However....

**parted -l**

```
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 275GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  275GB  275GB  primary  xfs
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=cdf895f5-190c-422a-b9a5-e8ba4cfad807       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
UUID=567781bc-8045-4e0d-a4f9-a971b671e920       /data    xfs   defaults,nofail,noatime         1 2
```

**mongodb.conf**

```
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/data/mongodb/data/db

#where to log
logpath=/data/mongodb/log/mongodb.log

logappend=true

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true
```

Comment: This startup message is only a warning, so you can ignore it if isn't relevant. What specific version of MongoDB server are you running? The journal config comment includes a suspiciously old docs link.

Comment: Iirc it was 3.2. Its based on the mongodb bitnami template in Azure marketplace.